# Помогите правильно написать print() Python re

Tags: python, print

```
import re
import sys

sys.stdout = open('out.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8')

res = []
with open(r'u.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fn:
    for line in fn:
        res.append("{1} {0}".format(*(line.split(";"))))

print(res, sep='\n')
```

Помогите пожалуйста правильно написать для этого скрипта print() чтобы результы выводил с новой строки
пробую:

```
print(res, sep='\n')
```

print выводит в одну строку

пробую:

```
print(*res, sep='\n')
```

ломает вывод

Comment: Что значит «ломает вывод»?

Comment: У меня в файле список ФИО;2021 мне нужно 2021 ФИО . Вывод print(*res, sep='\n') Выводит 2021 на одной строке ФИО с новой строки . А мне нужно чтобы каждая строка была 2021 ФИО.  Этот print(res, sep='\n') делает все правильно только выводит весь список в одну строку через запятую

Comment: Внутри `line` затесался символ перевода строки из файла, перед split'ом сделайте `line.strip()`

Comment: @andreymal Спасииииииииииибо ;)

Answer (score 3):

Судя по дополнениям в комментариях, вы работаете с CSV файлами. Для парсинга CSV файлов существует модуль [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). Но я бы посоветовал вам начать изучать модуль Pandas - если вам когда-нибудь понадобится читать/обрабатывать/визуализировать/записывать данные в табличном виде - Pandas идеально для этого подходит.

```
import pandas as pd

input_file = "..."
output_file = "..."
pd.read_csv(input_file, sep=";").to_csv(output_file, sep=" ", index=False)
```